# Issues installing IJulia

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, julia

unfortunately I’m not the most experienced Linux user and when I try to Pkg.build(“IJulia”). We have RHL installed on the university computers. I always get the following error msg. We have RHL installed on the university computers. Why is it showing python3.8 when I mostly use python2.7 how'd I change to the lower version as default?

```
INFO: Building Conda
INFO: Building MbedTLS
INFO: Building ZMQ
INFO: Building IJulia
Warning: `/nethome/harnold8/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/bin/jupyter --version` returned an unrecognized version number jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.2
qtconsole        : 4.6.0
ipython          : 7.11.1
ipykernel        : 5.1.3
jupyter client   : 5.3.4
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.3
traitlets        : 4.3.3
Info: /nethome/harnold8/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/bin/jupyter was too old: got 0.0.0, required ≥ 3.0
Info: Installing Jupyter via the Conda package.
Info: Running `conda install -y jupyter` in root environment
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                             

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                                                                                                                                                        
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - jupyter -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package ipython conflicts for:
jupyter -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0|>=4.0.0|>=5.0']
Package certifi conflicts for:
jupyter -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10'] -> numpydoc -> sphinx -> requests[version='>=2.0.0'] -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17']
jupyter -> jupyter_console -> pygments -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
jupyter -> ipykernel -> tornado[version='>=4.0'] -> certifi
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip -> wheel
jupyter -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package setuptools conflicts for:
jupyter -> jupyter_console -> pygments -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
Package python-dateutil conflicts for:
jupyter -> ipykernel -> jupyter_client -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.1']
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
jupyter -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip
jupyter -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip

=================================================================================================[ ERROR: IJulia ]=================================================================================================

LoadError: failed process: Process(setenv(`/nethome/harnold8/.conda/envs/conda_jl/bin/conda install -y jupyter`,String["PATH=/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/packages/miniconda3/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/nethome/harnold8/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/nethome/harnold8/.local/bin:/nethome/harnold8/bin", "QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3", "PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/nethome/harnold8/perl5", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-heXaYXpsli,guid=9dbf67b0dd4297c744095d1b5e1352bf", "MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles", "PERL5LIB=/nethome/harnold8/perl5/lib/perl5:", "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome-classic", "SSH_AGENT_PID=10081", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11", "USER=harnold8", "QT_IM_MODULE=xim", "USERNAME=harnold8", "GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic", "GDMSESSION=gnome-classic", "MATHEMATICA_HOME=/usr/local/packages/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2", "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/nethome/harnold8/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/", "LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins", "XDG_SEAT=seat0", "XAUTHORITY=/run/gdm/auth-for-harnold8-3uU2Qz/database", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-", "CONDARC=/nethome/harnold8/.conda/envs/conda_jl/condarc-julia.yml", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/9889,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/9889", "QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib", "XMODIFIERS=@im=none", "TERM=xterm-256color", "HOME=/nethome/harnold8", "HOSTNAME=eas-est-323503.eas.gatech.edu", "QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include", "VTE_VERSION=5202", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8", "HISTSIZE=1000", "PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=:/nethome/harnold8/perl5", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-Classic:GNOME", "LANG=en_US.UTF-8", "SHLVL=2", "LOADEDMODULES=", "IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP=yes", "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated", "LOGNAME=harnold8", "OLDPWD=/usr/local/packages/julia/d386e40c17", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/908581/keyring/ssh", "DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-classic", "GDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8", "IMSETTINGS_MODULE=none", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/908581", "_=/usr/local/bin/julia", "QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1", "GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/d4b04ad0_9e52_41ec_abc0_926decff4097", "GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.121", "PWD=/nethome/harnold8", "KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_908581_sBQoZH", "MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules", "DISPLAY=:0", "BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash \$*`\n}", "OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=8", "LD_PRELOAD=/nethome/harnold8/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/libz.so", "HISTCONTROL=ignoredups", "MAIL=/var/spool/mail/harnold8", "XDG_VTNR=1", "CONDA_PREFIX=/nethome/harnold8/.conda/envs/conda_jl", "XDG_SESSION_ID=3", "KDEDIRS=/usr", "PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base /nethome/harnold8/perl5", "WINDOWPATH=1", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"]), ProcessExited(1)) [1]
while loading /home/harnold8/.julia/v0.6/IJulia/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 125
```

Comment: you are using a very old Julia. Can you use 0.7 at least? or better 1.0.5 or 1.3.1?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I cannot, it's always a hustle getting the it guys things done... It worked before I updatet some packages. It was foolish, I know